# Why does Chrome not properly handle flexbox items added with jQuery?

Tags: jquery, html, css, flexbox

I was working on some basic flexbox code when I noticed that Chrome showed odd behavior when I added flex items and the direction of the container was set to `column` or `column-reverse`. Here's a simple flexbox example of things working properly with the direction set to column and wrapping on:

```css
#flexbox_container {
    border: 8px solid #ccc;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 200px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex_item {
    background: #eee;
    margin: 4px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div id="flexbox_container">
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
    <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
</div>
```

As expected, when the number of columns grows too large to fit the container, a second column is created with each item having equal width.

Now here's an example of the problem. If we start out with one column's worth of child flex items and use jQuery to keep adding more, instead of them being evenly divided as above, the first column takes up the full width, and the new items poke out to the side:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#flexbox_container').append('<div class="flex_item">Item</div>');
})
```

```css
#flexbox_container {
  border: 8px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex_item {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
</div>
<button>button</button>
```

What then confuses me is that if I fiddle with almost any CSS property, I can get Chrome to fall in line and display the flex items as I would expect them to (almost as if this redraws or recalculates the layout). For example, here I change the position of the flex items quickly after inserting a new item:

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#flexbox_container').append('<div class="flex_item">Item</div>');
  $('.flex_item').css('position', 'absolute')
  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.flex_item').css('position', 'relative')
  }, 0)
})
```

```css
#flexbox_container {
  border: 8px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.flex_item {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
</div>
<button>button</button>
```

Now that's obviously a hacky way to fix things and it causes an ugly flicker every time you add a new item.

So why does Chrome not display the flex items properly when they're inserted with jQuery, without having to resort to something like a quick modification to a CSS property?

Notice that neither Firefox nor Edge have this issue and work as expected, and adding `-webkit-` prefixes doesn't change the result. Also, this only seems to occur when the `flex-direction` is set to `column` or `column-reverse`. When it's set to `row` or `row-reverse` it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

Interesting.  You can fix the problem by adding these styles:

```
#flexbox_container {
  overflow: auto;
}

#flexbox_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}
```

Took a while to figure out that the height of the scrollbar needed to be 0.

Using `overflow` alone, Chrome seemed to do the following:

1. Add an element.
2. Add a scrollbar if needed.
3. Realize that this was a flexbox and it didn't need a scrollbar.
4. Incorrectly position the last element in a column to the top of the next column.

Remove the scrollbar CSS to see what I'm talking about.

```js
$('button').click(function() {
  $('#flexbox_container').append('<div class="flex_item">Item</div>');
})
```

```css
#flexbox_container {
  border: 8px solid #ccc;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 200px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  overflow: auto;
}
#flexbox_container::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;
}
.flex_item {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 4px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="flexbox_container">
  <div class="flex_item">Item</div>
</div>
<button>button</button>
```

Comment: Interesting work around. Does this behavior seem like a bug? I'm wondering if setting the height to zero on the scrollbar has any side effects.

Comment: It absolutely seems like a bug.  As long as the flexbox container *shouldn't* have a scrollbar, I don't think this should cause any problems.