# Flex on Chrome using jquery does not render properly

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome, flexbox

I have encountered some type of bug in chrome. In a nested flex, where the elements are added using jQuery, the layout does not render properly, until any css parameter is clicked off and on in the dev tools. I have not found a way to copy the dev tools checkbox in code. Changing css using javascript does not do anything (I've tried `jQuery.css()`, `elem.style`, `jQuery.addClass()`, and appending a `style` tag to head).

I've tried solutions in this question without luck:
[Why does Chrome not properly handle flexbox items added with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33681562/why-does-chrome-not-properly-handle-flexbox-items-added-with-jquery)

The only way to make it look right, is by changing parameters in dev tools, or maximizing/minimizing the chrome window. I don't care if the solution is hacky, I just want it to work in chrome. Other browsers display fine.

I've attached images, that display what is happening, when I disable and enable body width in dev tools.

[image: Initial Look]
[image: Bars show up when body width is off (or any other css parameter)]

[image: Bars remain when body width is set back]

Answer (score 0):

After researching, I've found a solution - add the following to the nested flex-container's child:

```
min-height: 0;
min-width: 0;
```